# CocoaPods trunk no Specs

Tags: cocoapods

I installed Cocoapods v1.7.0 on Mac Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2). Now I'm upgrading Cocoapods to v1.10.0.

Firstly I uninstall v1.7.0 following https://superuser.com/a/686319.

Then install v1.10.0 with no issue:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

In my project folder, I run `pod repo update`:

```
$pod repo update                    ✔  6s  17:17:13 
Updating spec repo `trunk`

$pod repo update                    ✔  3s  17:34:21
```

It only takes 3s with no issue, but I get **nothing in folder `~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs`(empty folder)**:(

Then as you may already know it cannot find any spec when running `pod install`:

```
pod install --repo-update
Updating local specs repositories
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `Firebase/Analytics`

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

> Note: Not pod `Firebase/Analytics` issue, tried other pods also got this error.

Any suggestion to fetch **Cococapods CDN trunk Specs** normally? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue, any process?

Answer (score 0):

It's working by uninstalling CocoaPods v1.10.0 & then installing v1.8.0.
Don't know the root cause yet, guess have to install the first CocoaPods version with CDN.